# ln -s removes part of a file name, when filename is passed as a variable

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, ln

I use a script to link some of the files I download to a different directory. When there are "-" in the file name, ln - s wont read the path correctly, even though the variable will be logged correctly to the log file I use.

```
for f in ${AVIFILES}
do
        BaseAviName=$(basename "$f" .avi)
        aviMp4name="'""$targetdir""/""$BaseAviName"".mp4""'"
        linkAviFile="'""$targetdir""/""$f""'"
        downloadedFile=$("'""$theFile""/""$f""'")
        ln -s "$downloadedFile" "$linkAviFile" >>$logPath 2>&1
        echo "fileIs: " "$f" ",linkAviFile is" "$linkAviFile" ",BaseAviName:" "$BaseAviName" '$aviMp4name: ' "$aviMp4name" '$downloadedFile: ' "$downloadedFile" >> "$logPath"   
done
```

That's the error message from `ln`:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘'/home/user/Videos/TVEpisodes/Parks and Recreation/Parks.and.Recreation.S03E01.DVDRip.XviD-REWARD.avi'’ -> ‘’: No such file or directory
```

Even though the variable downloadedFile is logged with the correct path:

```
'/home/user/Downloads/Parks And Recreation - Season 3 - DVDRip-REWARD/Parks.and.Recreation.S03E01.DVDRip.XviD-REWARD.avi'
```

It seems, that for some reason, that when $downloadedFile is expanded for ln to work with it, ln will omit part of the filename, from the first "-" to the next "/" ( - Season 3 - DVDRip-REWARD"). I can't find a good reason why this happens, and want to avoid it, any suggestions...

EDIT: I rewrote the script and the problem disappeared. Thanks to anyone who helped

Comment: It's possible that `ln` is interpreting the dash as the start of a flag. Try: `ln -s -- "$downloadedFile" "$linkAviFile" >>$logPath 2>&1`

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve - first of all why your script is so complicated with multiple quotes? Secondly variable `downloadedFile` is defined with command substitution, but there is no command there, only some variables and quotes, and `targetdir` as well as `theFile` are not defined anywhere. You should edit the question and post minimal working example of the problem.

Comment: Well, they are defined, thats just not the whole script, thats the relevant part. They expand correctly, when echoed, but not when passed to the ln command. I added all the quotes so I can have the correct file name and path passed to ln , but not working

Comment: try putting `echo` in front of the `ln`. Remember `bash` does the expansion, so it is the some for any command.

Comment: Can I have an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even though the variable downloadedFile is logged with the correct path:
>
> ```
> '/home/user/Downloads/Parks And Recreation - Season 3 - DVDRip-REWARD/Parks.and.Recreation.S03E01.DVDRip.XviD-REWARD.avi'
> ```

That's evidently not the correct path: it has extra `'` characters at the beginning and at the end. You can see that in the error message from `ln`:

> ```
> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘'/home/user/Videos/TVEpisodes/Parks and Recreation/Parks.and.Recreation.S03E01.DVDRip.XviD-REWARD.avi'’ -> ‘’: No such file or directory
> ```

The error message has the file name inside ‘single quotes’, and there are extra `'` (ASCII single quotes) characters at the beginning and at the end.

The problem in your script is obvious: you're adding extra `'` characters when defining `aviMp4name`, `linkAviFile` and `downloadedFile`. Don't do that.

```
for f in "${AVIFILES[@]}"
do
    BaseAviName=$(basename -- "$f" .avi)
    aviMp4name="$targetdir/$BaseAviName.mp4"
    linkAviFile="$targetdir/$f"
    downloadedFile=$("$theFile/$f")
    ln -s -- "$downloadedFile" "$linkAviFile" >>$logPath 2>&1
    echo "fileIs: " "$f" ",linkAviFile is" "$linkAviFile" ",BaseAviName:" "$BaseAviName" '$aviMp4name: ' "$aviMp4name" '$downloadedFile: ' "$downloadedFile" >> "$logPath"   
done
```

In the shell *source syntax*, single quotes delimit literal strings, for example `a='hello world!'` sets the variable `a` to the 12-character string `hello world!`. If you put single quotes *into a variable*, you get single quotes back: `a="'hello world!'"` sets `a` to the 14-character string `'hello world!'`.

The key thing to remember with quotes in shell scripts is to put double quotes around variable expansions, e.g. `ln -s -- "$downloadedFile" "$linkAviFile"`. Code like `ln -s -- $downloadedFile $linkAviFile` would split the values of the variables `downloadedFile` and `linkAviFile` at whitespace characters and would interpret each piece as a wildcard pattern. Those double quotes are part of the shell source syntax, they're interpreted by the parser. Putting quotes into a variable's value won't solve anything.

Also note that if a file name begins with a `-`, it will be interpreted as an option by the command. To avoid this, when you have file names in variables, pass the argument `--` to the command after all options and before all file names (you can omit `--` if you're sure the file names don't begin with `-`, for example if you know they're absolute paths). `--` means “no more options after this point”.

Note that `${AVIFILES}` would, like any other unquoted expansion, split the value of the variable at whitespace. To store multiple file names in a variable, make it an array instead of a string; this requires ksh, bash or zsh, it doesn't work in plain sh:

```
AVIFILES=(foo.avi bar.avi "file name with spaces.avi")
```

Comment: The problem is not about spaces at all. Its about dashes. I just tried your version, and I get the same result - the part for the first dash to the consecutive "/" is omitted by ln, while trying to create the link. This part is MISSING,( - Season 3 - DVDRip-REWARD"), while the filename goes on. I think its ln being messed by the "-" in the filename, thats why I tried to add single quotes where ever possible..

Comment: @deckoff When you have file names that might begin with dashes, make sure to pass `--` before the file names, as otherwise the files would be interpreted as options. I did that in my code example but I'll add a note in the text as well. Once again, by addng quotes inside the string, you're just passing a different file name, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, I removed the quotes and tried with the code you suggested. I got the exact same result. I added -- too, sadly this did not change anything. The file does not start with dash, it's in the middle of it. I am starting to think it might be a weird kind of bug, even. I will edit the question a bit, and link to the whole script. AVIFILES should not be quoted, it's equal to *.avi, so the script with cycle over all avi files in the dir.

Comment: @deckoff If you want more help, you'll need to provide more information, such as the value of `AVIFILES`, what files are there, and, crucially, what the command `"$theFile/$f"` does! It uses a variable that isn't defined in your snippet and you use its output as a file name.